# Volume mounted to NTFS folder (C:\Temp) disappears randomly

Tags: windows-7, mount, ntfs

I have my temp directory (C:\Temp - system variable) mounted to an NTFS folder on an SSD (via Diskmanagement > Change or Assign Drive Letters > mount to empty NTFS folder).

This mounting behaviour is not affected by logging on / off or system restart. However, the mount will disappear randomly, most notably when closing Visual Studio, but also on other occasions. When this happens, a new Temp directory will be created on C:\, which is then used henceforth, meaning I have to empty it, and remount to volume into C:\Temp (all the data on the volume is retained).

Does anybody know the cause of this strange behavior, and know how to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the cause, but you may have better luck using a soft link to point to your drive instead of an ntfs folder, being that this is a windows generated folder. Does the same behavior happen if you use a different folder? assigning your ssd to C:\Temp2 or to C:\user\\documents\special_folder for example? if the behavior doesn't exist when it's mounted to a different (non system) folder, you can assume that the reason is because of where you've chosen to mount it.

Comment: Hi MDMoore,
this behaviour only occurs with the temp folder; have another folder mounted in this way, and it is absolutely fine.
Softlink not bad idea - will give it a try, though I am concerned that the result will be the same, namely Windows deleting the link and creating a directory.
Pretty sure the location of the mount is not the issue, as the other (persistent) folder is mounted to a partition on the same drive.

Comment: make sure if you try the softlink you use `mklink /d`, as the default is a file symbolic link and not a directory.